# Need to calculate series equation converging to π

Tags: c++

First time programming and I’ve got to write a program that calculates the series equation
(n!)^2*2^n+1/(2n+1)!, n being the amount of terms the user inputs.

I’ve got it to where the user inputs n and I get the answer for that number only.

How do I make it so that I get the sum of all answers from 0 to the user input?

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double i,n,factorial,factorial2,n2,a; 
    a = 1;
    cout<<"Enter # of terms:";
    cin>>n;

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)

    if (i == 0)
        factorial = 1;
    else
        factorial = factorial * i;

    factorial = pow(factorial,2)*pow(2,n+1);

    n2 = 2*n+a;

    for (i = 0; i <= n2; i++)

    if (i == 0)
    factorial2 = 1;
    else
    factorial2 = factorial2 * i;
    factorial = factorial/factorial2;

    cout<<factorial<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Wait... *what* does the user provide?

Comment: "get the sum of all terms the user inputs?" - not sure why you want to do it, but that sounds like `double n, total = 0; while (std::cin >> n) total += n; std::cout << "total " << total << '\n';`.

Comment: n terms. so user input is 4, get the sum of the results of 4,3,2,1, and 0 in the equation?

Comment: @jim: ok then, so change to `total += f(n);`, and above `main()` insert `int factorial(int n) { return n <= 1 ? 1 : factorial(n - 1) * n; }`, then your function `double f(double n) { return std::pow(fact(n),2) * std::pow(2, n) + 1 / factorial(2 * n + 1); }`.  That simple.  (I've assumed you'd parenthesised as necessary so the precedence was correct, given the norms in mathematics, if not - edit the above).  Posted as an answer for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Use a loop that will go through each n;
- Make a recursive function:

  ```
  // In pseudocode
  term (n){
  if ( n < 0 ) return 0;

  // calculate y for this n;
  return y + term( n - 1 );
  }
  ```

A recursive function (assuming you're familiar with functions) is a function that calls itself to solve a problem. For example, n! = (n - 1)! * n. You can use this simple fact an create a factorial function f ( n ) that returns n * f ( n - 1 ) unless n is 1 (returns 1 in this case).

I'll develop the first option:

```
// I assumed your code is working and that factorial holds the values you want to sum.
// If that's not the case, I believe you can use it to solve your problem anyway

#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double n, total = 0;
    cout << "Enter # of terms:";
    cin  >> n;

    while (n >= 0) {
        double i, factorial, factorial2, n2, a;

        a = 1;

        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            if (i == 0)
                factorial = 1;
            else
                factorial = factorial * i;
        }

        factorial = pow(factorial, 2)*pow(2, n + 1);

        n2 = 2 * n + a;

        for (i = 0; i <= n2; i++) {
            if (i == 0)
                factorial2 = 1;
            else
                factorial2 = factorial2 * i;

            factorial = factorial / factorial2;
        }

        total += factorial;
        n--;
    }
    cout << total << endl;
}
```

Hope it helps :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code from my comments, all laid out to be readable...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int factorial(int n)
{
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : factorial(n - 1) * n;
}
```

OR if you find that factorial function confusing, SlySherZ suggested this beginner-friendly alternative (you don't want *both* implementations).

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    return factorial(n - 1) * n;
}
```

Continuing...

```
double f(double n)
{
    return std::pow(fact(n),2) * std::pow(2, n) + 1 / factorial(2 * n + 1);
}

int main()
{
    double n, total = 0;
    while (std::cin >> n)
        total += f(n);
    std::cout << "total " << total << '\n';
}
```